# Using Sessions (or otherwise) what can I do to make my page remember the variables when I go back to it?

Tags: php, session, variables

On this page, `volleyLogin.php`, when the user hits it for the first time everything works well - they log in with their username and from there can go on to `AddNew.php`. When the user clicks 'Create' on `AddNew.php`, it goes back automatically to `volleyLogin.php`. The details of `AddNew.php` are saved to the mysql database, but on going back to `volleyLogin.php` we see :

http://screencast.com/t/esgXUJlMa

which is the line :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
```

How can I fix this ?

Here's my code:

volleyLogin.php

```
   <?php
require('dbConnect.php');

//if the session is already active, like we are coming back to this page from AddNew.php
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
//session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
}

 //if user is logging in
    if(isset($_POST['username'])){
//helps stop sql injection
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);

 } 

//select everything from user
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
//get the result of the above
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
//get every other record in the same row 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//make the user_id record in that row a variable 
    $user_id = $row["user_id"];
    $username = $row["username"];
    echo "user id is " . $user_id . "<br>";
    echo "user name is " . $username . "<br>";

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id']= $user_id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM review WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";


    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

//if username isn't in the db
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) {
    echo "Failed, sorry";
}

//if username is in the db
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        //if username has reviews in the db
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

        $review_id=$rows['review_id'];
        $_SESSION['review'] = $review_id;

        echo "review id is " . $review_id  . "<br>";
        echo  "<br>";
        echo "Category: " . $rows['cat_name'] . "<br>";
        echo "Name: " . $rows['name'] . "<br>";
        echo "Phone: " . $rows['phone'] . "<br>";

//html stuff comes next
        ?>
        <!-- show the + button, click for more details -->
                <html>
    <body>

    <form action="showreview.php?id=<?=$review_id?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="+" name="show_review"><br>

    </form>
    <p></p>
    </body>
    </html>

        <?php   
}

            ?>

        <html>
    <body>

    <form action="AddNew.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Add New" name="username"><br>

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

<?php       



}


    $con->close();
?>
```

AddNew.php

```
<?php require('dbConnect.php'); 

//use the variables we created in volleyLogin.php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    echo "user name is " . $username . "<br>";
    echo "user id is " . $user_id . "<br>"; 

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

    $category = ($_POST['category']);
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $phonenumber = ($_POST['phonenumber']);
    $address = ($_POST['address']);
    $comment = ($_POST['comment']);


//in the review table, create a new id, put in the cat_id it comes under, the user id...
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO review VALUES(NULL,'666','{$category}','$user_id', '{$name}','{$phonenumber}','{$address}', '{$comment}')";


        if ($con->query($sql2) === TRUE) {

    header('Location:volleyLogin.php');

    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

}


    $con->close();


?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h2>Create new Contact</h2>
    <form method="post" action="" name="frmAdd">
    <p><input type="text" name = "category" id = "category" placeholder = "category"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "name" id = "name" placeholder = "name"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "phonenumber" id = "phonenumber" placeholder = "phone number"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "address" id = "address" placeholder = "address"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name = "comment" id = "comment" placeholder = "comment"></p>
    <h2>Visible to :</h2>
    <input type="radio" name="allmycontacts" value="All my Contacts">All my Contacts
    <input type="radio" name="selectwho" value="Select Who">Select Who
    <input type="radio" name="public" value="Public">Public
    <input type="radio" name="justme" value="Just me">Just me

    <p><input type="submit" name = "create" id = "create" value = "Create new Contact"></p>
    <a href="exit.php">Exit</a>

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems to me like the session didn't get started for the volleyLogin.php file. From the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php `if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {session_start();}` - This of course being a negation method, but the principle's the same. Have you started the session for it?

Comment: You should also check if the session array is set/not empty for all files using sessions. Edit: About my comment above; I noticed it now. You should move it just under your 3rd line of code where you have it commented out actually `//session_start();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, strange.

In my volleyLogin.php I have :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']= $user_id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

I simply took `session_start();` out of there and put it right at the very top, after my opening
`<?php` tag and now it works correctly.